How to debug exceptions in the Intel Software Development Emulator?
I use the Intel Software Development Emulator to run a program using AVX-512 instructions that aren't supported on my computer.
When running it, I get the following exception:
Thread: 553
PID: 12345
SYSTEM TID: 13315
Exception code: ACCESS_DENIED
Exception Class: 2
Faulty AccessType : 0
Exception address: 0x7be3bc4875fe
C: [tid:13315] Tool (or Pin) caused signal 11 at PC 0x7be3bc4875fe
C: [tid:13315] Location may be in in-lined analysis code, try re-running with '-inline 0' to debug itfish: Job 1, 'sde -future -rtm_mode full -- /…' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

How can I debug this? I tried adding -debug but the debugger will not stop when there's a segfault in this case (other cases of segfaults get caught by the debugger, but not this one).
When running with -ptr-check, I can sometimes get a better error:
SDE ERROR: DEREFERENCING BAD MEMORY POINTER PC=0x5a283b7f07cf MEMEA=0x7baf9fa00f00 vmovdqa64 zmmword ptr [rsp+0x6188], zmm0

, but it's still not enough information for me: I would need a stacktrace.

Is that saying that Pin or SDE's own Pintool code segfaulted, rather than the "guest" code running inside it?  That could be a bug in SDE.  The error message suggests running with -inline 0; does that help?  Either way, you might try asking about this on the Intel forums.  Especially if you can create a [mcve] that can reproduce this non-debuggable crash, in which case it could make a good SDE bug report.  (Might be a lot of work, and Intel engineers might be willing to do that for you if you don't mind sending them your full code.  Stack Overflow requires users to make their own MCVEs.)
